# Measuring spring batch step execution time

Tags: java, spring-batch

What is the correct way to measure the step execution time in spring batch ?

here is an example of step :

```
@Bean
    public Step step1() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<POJO, POJO> chunk(10)
                .reader(pojoReader())
                .processor(pojoProcessor())
                .build();
    }
```

I sow some example using before step on ItemWriter an IemReader

```
public class xxxxxItemReader implements xxxxItemReader <XXXX>{

    private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        //
        // Can Log || do some business code
        //
        log.info("Intercepting Job Excution - Before Job!");
    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        //
        // Can Log || do some Business code
        //
        log.info("Intercepting Job Excution - After Job!");
    }

}
```

in this case i should have a before step and after step with my ItemWriter and itemReader and final put it together (addition) to get the holl step execution time ? Is it the best Way ?

Comment: A full step execution time is available in meta data. Did you meant chunk time ( read - process - write time ) ? or only read, process & write times individually?

Comment: Yes I'm looking for the hole execution step time . is there a place that i can get this information without passing by listeners

Comment: Why so complex? The `StepExecution` already contains the start and end time, you can just calculate it in an `afterStep`. You don't need to do anything special for that. Next to that Spring Batch stores all this information in the datastore you choose for the metadata (in-memory or db).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The listener that you have shared is a `org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionListener` while for similar methods for a step , you need to use - `org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecutionListener` and implement methods - `void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution)` & `ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution);`

Create a listener class by implementing above interface & configure in your step.

Then define an instance field in this listener like - `long startTime` and set it to something like `startTime= System.nanoTime();` in `beforeStep` then in `afterStep` , this string can be passed on your logger to log times in milli seconds - `(System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1e6 + "ms."`

Alternately, meta DB table - `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION` has these times - `START_TIME` & `END_TIME` columns. You can write a script to dump these times to some file or retrieve in any desired format.

I am not sure if you are using Spring Boot but refer [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-spring-batch-database)

Also, make sure that your configuration is not using in - memory repository with HSQL or H2 databases.

Comment: Thanks, just as I'm newbie in spring batch is these DB tables are created automatically ? haw can i access them ?

Comment: It depends on your overall set up and user rights for user running the job. Scripts are in - `spring-batch-core` jar's `org.springframework.batch.core` package. Review it for your database. You can create these six tables manually too with taking help from statements from those SQL files. `spring.batch.initializer.enabled` is the property that decides if you need to execute those scripts automatically.

Comment: Thank you for you kind help

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JobExecutionListener` on the Job :

```
@Bean
public Job helloJob() {
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("HelloJob")
        ...
        .listener(new JobExecutionListener() 
        {

            @Override
            public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) 
            {
                // do nothing
            }

            @Override
            public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) 
            {
                // get job's start time
                Date start = jobExecution.getCreateTime();

                //  get job's end time
                Date end = jobExecution.getEndTime();

                // get diff between end time and start time
                long diff = end.getTime() - start.getTime();

                // log diff time
                log.info(TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
            }
        })
        ...
        .build();
}
```